Hyperplane tangent to variety iff the intersection is singular when $n=2$
Several Stack Exchange posts state variations of:
Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a smooth irreducible projective variety. Let $H \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a hyperplane. The hyperplane section $H \cap X$ is smooth at $p$ if and only if the hyperplane $H$ is not tangent to $X$ at $p$.
But I am puzzled by this example when $n=2$.
Suppose $X = \mathbb{V}(zy-x^2)$ and $p = (0, 0, 1)$, then work in $\mathbb{A}^2$ giving $\mathbb{V}(y - x^2)$.  The hyperplane $H = \mathbb{V}(y)$ is tangent at $p$, but the intersection $X \cap H = \{(0,0)\}$ appears smooth, since it has dimension $0$ and its tangent space has dimension $0$.  Is my example wrong, or does the statement above need an additional hypothesis?
References:

Hyperplane tangent to a projective variety.
Bertini Theorem & Hyperplane section $H \cap X$ smooth
singular intersection only comes from tangent?


You have to be really careful here: Are you working with varieties or schemes? If you work with varieties, then "if and only if" is false. The linked answers are sloppy in this regard.

To add to the previous comment, $X \cap H$ is not reduced, so it’s not smooth. If you don’t have the language of schemes, it’s not clear how to consider the nilpotent data of $X \cap H$ which is exactly the non-smoothness.
